# getJSON to array on object creation

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have made an array in my class, but I want create it with a json. But I cannot add this like that.

```
var  myclass = {
    test:0,
    testbis:0,
    thirdtest:JSON.parse($.getJSON("my/path/to/json"))
};
```

and my json

```
{"1":"first","2":"second","3":"third"}
```

I want to create it when I create my object "myclass". How can I do this please?

Comment: $.getJSON("my/path/to/json") does not return data. use the documentation to understand how it works http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/ .

Comment: You may want to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/34594985/edit) and add a tag so we know what language you are working in.

Comment: So do you know an alternative?

Comment: @JeffBridgman Sorry, and thank for the advise.

Comment: That's not how getJSON works at all. If you find the API documentation too abstract, why don't you just copy an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the data is not available until the AJAX call succeeds, you should create your object inside the success callback:

```
$.getJSON("my/path/to/json", function(data) {
    var myclass = {
        test: 0,
        testbis: 0,
        // Notice that you don't need JSON.parse here because the $.getJSON
        // method will already do this for you
        thirdtest: data
    };

     // now you could use the myclass instance here.
});
```